# LINQ query returning no rows

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

I'm new to LINQ, so I'm sure there's an error in my logic below.

I have a list of objects:

```
class Characteristic
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public bool IsIncluded { get; set; }
}
```

**Using each object in the list, I want to build a query in LINQ that starts with a `DataTable`, and filters it based on the object values, and yields a `DataTable` as the result.**

My Code so far:

```
DataTable table = MyTable;
// Also tried: DataTable table = MyTable.Clone();

foreach (Characteristic c in characteristics)
{
  if (c.IsIncluded)
  {
    var q = (from r in table.AsEnumerable()
             where r.Field<string>(c.Name) == c.Value
             select r);
  }
  else
  {
    var q = (from r in table.AsEnumerable()
             where r.Field<string>(c.Name) != c.Value
            select r);
  }

  table = q.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: Solutions go in answers, not in edits to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The logic in your posting is wonky; here is my attempt of what I *think* you are trying to achieve.

```
DataTable table = MyTable.AsEnumerable()
     .Where(r => characteristics.All(c => !c.IsIncluded ||
                                          r.Field<string>(c.Name) == c.Value))
     .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you actually want to use the logic in your posting, change `||` to `^`, but that seems to make little sense.

Comment: Error: `The source contains no DataRows.`

Comment: you are right, it is *wonky*, but unfortunately, the input spreadsheets were not designed by someone with a firm grasp on relational table concepts.  You know how that stuff goes...

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the `table` variable  for each characteristic, so in the end it only holds the results from the last round, and that that apparently is empty.

What you could do is something like:

```
// untested
var t = q.CopyToDataTable();
table.Merge(t);
```

And I suspect your query should use MyTable as the source:

```
var q = (from r in MyTable.AsEnumerable() ...
```

But that's not entirely clear.

Comment: I want to overwrite it, because I want to apply *ALL* the filters.  Even after the first iteration, the table appears empty.  That's also why I choose to create a new `DataTable` reference for this code block.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to just insert the rows into your table then try calling the CopyToDataTable method this way:

```
q.CopyToDataTable(table, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
```

This way rather than reassigning the table variable you can just update it with the new rows that are to be inserted.

EDIT: Here is an example of what I was talking about:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
```

Comment: Oh, start with an empty table, then add rows that match the filter, great idea!  *(I think Henk assumed I was already thinking on those lines, oops, +1 to you too.)*

Comment: I think what @Henk was saying is that it appears that you are overwriting your table variable every time you find a match. That is why at best you are only going to have the last set of matching rows in your table instead of all the matches for every filter.

Comment: Error: `Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.`

Comment: If you are using the above code then yes you would get an error because your datatable does not have any columns in it. Let me put in an edit using your code and see if that works for you.

Comment: Ok so I showed you how you need to add columns to the table. So just make sure that every column that is in myTable which is where you are pulling the matching rows from is in table which is where you are trying to put those rows. Just think about it as sql. You can't insert rows into a table that doesn't have the correct columns. If you don't want to put all the same columns because maybe you don't need them then change your LINQ statement to only return the columns you want.